# How do I search find files and compress if greater than 500M

Tags: find, gzip

I need to find files greater than 500M and older than 1 day and I need to compress those files. Also I need to omit files with .gz extension. How can it be achieved?

Answer (score 3):

```
LC_ALL=C find . ! -name '*.gz' \
                -type f \
                -size +"$((500*1024*1024))c" \
                -mtime +0 \
                -exec gzip {} +
```

Here using `gzip` for compression. See also `xz`, `bzip2` or `compress` for other compression utilities with different compression formats.

Note that some `find` implementations like GNU `find` also support `-size +500M`.

You can add the `-v` option to `gzip` to get some information on the progress.

If both `file` and `file.gz` exist, you'll get a confirmation prompt. Add  the `-f` option if you want to force the zipping, or add `< /dev/null` if you don't want the `file.gz` overridden and don't want to have to answer a prompt.

Note that `-mtime +0` checks if the age in integer number of days rounded **down** is greater than 0, so will be true for files whose age is 1 day or more, while `-size +500M` checks if the size in integer number of mebibytes rounded **up** is greater than `500`, so will be true for files whose size is *strictly* greater than 500M (524288000 bytes).

The `LC_ALL=C` is to make sure that `*.gz` matches files whose name ends in `.gz` regardless of whether the start of the filename contains valid characters in the current locale or not. That has the size effect of affecting the language of the error messages though.

If you want to check what it would do without actually doing it, replace `gzip` with `echo gzip`.

Comment: Could you please explain me how it works.?

Comment: Does it omit .gz extension?

Comment: and for older than one day use '-mtime +1' (modified time) or '-ctime +1' (creation time greater than one day)

Comment: I understood. But please let me know whether it avoids file with .gz extension?

Comment: @sabarishjackson, in the first version, I had forgotten the `!`. `! -name '*.gz'` matches on file names that don't end in `.gz`.

Comment: yup actually it is '-mtime +0' , or '-not -mtime -1'

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Is there any way to echo an output to a file? adding to the same find command. I need to send output "The following files are being compressed" to a file name.

will this work?

** find ${SEARCH_DIR} -maxdepth 1 ! -name '*.gz' -type f -size +${SIZE} -exec echo "THE FLLOWING ARE TO BE COMPRESSED" {} \;2>/dev/null > filelist  **

Comment: @sabarishjackson I was about to answer your other question before you deleted it (why?). `gzip` normally has no output, so at least add `-v` to gzip to get some output when it does something. You can then transform that with e.g. `sed` to extract only the filename from the output.

Comment: @Anthon yeah. Actually I did it using if [ $? -eq 0]. That worked. That's why i deleted it. Thanks. :)